Getting a "Route has an invalid export" error when building my website
Hi I'm getting a "Route has an invalid export" error when building my code on vercel. It's working fine locally so I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong here.
This is the GET function in my API folder:
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';

export async function GET() {
    try {
        const session = await getServerSession();

        const _response = await sql`
        SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE email=${session.user.email}`;

        const data = _response.rows[0]
        return {
            id: data.id,
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
            unit: data.unit,
            name: data.name,
            language: data.language,
            country: data.country
          };

    } catch (e) {
        console.log({e});
    }
}

and this is a snippet of the code I'm using for the front end:
import { Card, CardHeader, Form, Input } from "@nextui-org/react"
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { GET } from '../api/auth/account/route'

export default async function AccountDetails() {
    const session = await getServerSession();
    const userData = await GET();
    return (
                <Form
                    className="flex flex-row"
                    validationBehavior="native">

                <div className="px-8">
                    <label className="block mt-4 mb-2 text-left text-gray-700 font-bold">Language</label>
                    <Input
                        errorMessage="Please enter a valid email"
                        name="language"
                        className="block w-full mb-6 px py border border-gray-300 rounded-xl focus:outline-none focus:border-green-400"
                        placeholder={userData?.language}
                        type="language"
                    /></div>

This is my file structure:

If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated. Thank you!!

Try returning NextResponse in your route instead on Json

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
